# Difference in IP addresses

Tags: networking, ip

I have noticed that ipconfig and a website that tells you what your ip is, are different.

Two cases:

1. E.g. I rdp from my laptop to my PC via an IP on that is always in the same network ID (so first 3 parts of the IP - can't remember exact term - do not change). A website gives a different IP, often starting with 80.
2. I run my own servers on the cloud. They have static, private IPs, thus only accessible via a VPN. I can map public IPs to the servers via NAT. However, an app I use (mobilepcmonitor) which allows me to control my servers from my phone, reports another IP.

Why are there differences?

Comment: Working on it, I am retrospectively approving questions! :)

Comment: Good stuff :) Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the keyword - NAT (Network address translation).

Usually (in home networks and most corporate networks), users are assigned private IP addresses (ie 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x,... 192.168.x.x). When they connect to the internet, their router translates those addresses to one (or more) external IP(s). (for example the one starting with 80.), but their "ipconfig" still shows their internal (private) IP.

If any of the IPs you see are from the private range (mentioned above), it is perfectly normal that the external IP is different from internal one (that's why we have NAT, so we can put many computers in a network, and connect them all to the internet, using just one external IP).

Comment: I see. So if I was to rdp to my machine from outside its network, which would I use?

Comment: If you want to RDP from outside, you first need to set port forwarding on your router, so your router will forward connections (to rdp port) from your public ip, to your internal ip). So you would add a rule to forward port 3389 (RDP) to your internal ip (you have that setting somewhere on your router), and then connect to your external (80.some.thi.ng) IP when outside your network.

Comment: The public one obviously, as the private address is, well... private. But it's not going to work unless the router is configured to do port-forwarding. Consider this: The router has 1 public ip with multiple private ip's behind it. If it receives incoming rdp it has no way of telling which internal private ip must receive the traffic. It needs to be configured to forward incoming rdp to the correct private ip. That's what is called port-forwarding. I suggest you read up on NAT and port-forwarding. Wikipedia is a good starting point.